# What is causing the error in this program

Tags: python, variables, python-3.x, variable-assignment

I am having a bit of trouble with a program that I made. I am not quite sure what the problem is. However, I cannot think of what to search for to solve the problem. Since this is the case, I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question.

```
# convert.py
# A program to convert Celsius temps to Fahrenheit

def main():
    print("Hello", end=" ")
    print("this program will convert any 5 different celsius temperatures to fahrenheit.")
    c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = eval(input("Please enter 5 different celsius temperatures seperated by commas: "))
    print(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
    for i in range(5):
        c = ("c" + str(i + 1))
        print(c)
        fahrenheit = 9/5 * c + 32
        print("The temperature is", fahrenheit, "degrees Fahrenheit.")
    input("The program has now finished press enter when done: ")

main()
```

This program works fine up until the Fahrenheit assignment statement on the first loop. I am sure that the problem involves the variables and the most likely incorrect way that I have assigned them. So I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out what I am doing wrong and why it will not work.

Comment: 99 times out of 100, if you're trying to dynamically access variables, you're doing something wrong. Keep the input as a tuple (`temperatures = eval(input(...))`) and iterate over it (`for temperature in temperatues:`)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty close, but don't convert to strings:

```
def main():
    print("Hello", end=" ")
    print("this program will convert any 5 different celsius temperatures to fahrenheit.")
    temps = eval(input("Please enter 5 different celsius temperatures seperated by commas: "))
    print(*temps)
    for c in temps:
        print(c)
        fahrenheit = 9/5 * c + 32
        print("The temperature is", fahrenheit, "degrees Fahrenheit.")
    input("The program has now finished press enter when done: ")

main()
```

It is not recommend to use `eval` as the user can execute arbitrary Python code. Better convert the numbers explicitly:

```
prompt = "Please enter 5 different celsius temperatures seperated by commas: "
temps = [int(x) for x in input(prompt).split(',')]
```

This:

```
c = ("c" + str(i + 1))
```

creates the strings `'c1'`, `'c2'` and so on. They are different than the names `c1`and `c2` you assign in the line with `input`. It is easier to put all values the user enters in `temp`. It does not matter if it is one, two, ten or one hundred. Python allows to loop of `temps` directly with:

```
for c in temps:
```

Here `c` become each number in turn that is store in `temps`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am still extremely new to programming and do not know what can and can't be done quite yet.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your attempt was pretty good  already. We are all here to learn. :)